# Configuring JBoss 7.x in domain mode with negative port offset

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I would like to change the default port of JBoss 7 in both standalone and domain mode to 5050:

`http://localhost:5050`

In standlone mode, I simply changed the below property in standlone.xml:

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="5050"/>
```

In domain mode, however, I have the option to only change the offset in host.xml:

```
<server name="server-one" group="main-server-group">
        <!-- Remote JPDA debugging for a specific server
        <jvm name="default">
          <jvm-options>
            <option value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"/>
          </jvm-options>
       </jvm>
       -->
    <socket-bindings port-offset="5"/>

    </server>
    <server name="server-two" group="main-server-group" auto-start="true">
        <!-- server-two avoids port conflicts by incrementing the ports in
             the default socket-group declared in the server-group -->
        <socket-bindings port-offset="10"/>
    </server>
```

When I try setting a negative port-offset, the startup script throws an error. How can I change the port from 8080 to 5050 in domain mode?

Comment: Try create a new `socket-binding-group` and set it `<socket-binding-group ref="offset-sockets"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Create system property in host.xml for "jboss.http.port" like :

```
    <server name="server-two" group="main-server-group" auto-start="true">
        <system-properties>
            <property name="jboss.http.port" value="4950" boot-time="true"/>
        </system-properties>
        <socket-bindings port-offset="100"/>
    </server>
```

Just make sure that port-offset value must be deducted from 5050.